# GRUB menu stopped showing in serial console

Tags: boot, grub2

Until recently, on my Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS, the GRUB menu had been showing as desired in the serial console, but at some point it stopped and I don't know why.  Everything AFTER the GRUB menu works fine in the serial console, and the GRUB menu does still shows as expected on the desktop monitor.

Below is the configuration settings:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200n8"
GRUB_TERMINAL="console serial"
GRUB_SERIAL_COMMAND="serial --speed=115200 --word=8 --parity=no --stop=1 --unit=0"
```

Maybe I accidentally uninstalled or changed something vital, but I don't know what.  What do I need to do get GRUB menu to show in the serial console?

Comment: I'm certainly not experienced in this... but it looking at your line "console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200n8" it looks like you're specifying two destinations with console=? And does ",115200n8" need to be there?

Comment: yes two destinations, the attached monitor as well as serial console.  i'm not sure about the ",115200n8" is **required**.  are you suggesting this is the cause?

Comment: You specify the speed/data bits in the GRUB_SERIAL_COMMAND, so if the format is correct, then you shouldn't need the 115200n8. Earlier, when specifying two destinations, did that work before? It seems very strange to me. I can't speak with any specific experience with doing this... it's just that your GRUB mods look "funny".

Answer (score 0):

I have seen the same problem in Ubuntu 18.04, but I cannot tell how it works in other releases since I haven't tried. After following many post on internet. My grub setup is
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="console=ttyS0"
GRUB_TEMRINAL="serial console"

No need to set GRUB_SERIAL_COMMAND. The trick is to use virt-manager to view the grub menu in text if you have -nographic or  section in xml is removed.